# sql except and update data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a DTS package scheduled that synchronizes file ODBC data into my SQL Database. It stores the data into a temporary table, then I process the information. Its been running as an INSERT, NOT IN, but am now changing it to also update the rows that have changed. Can you help with a strategy to remove the records that have changed so that it will reinsert the rows, or UPDATE the rows. I tried wrapping the EXCEPT in a SELECT * FROM but the query ran over 30 seconds, where the EXCEPT itself takes MS. Would a DELETE FROM work against the EXCEPT? There are 30+ columns, so writing out the UPDATE seems lengthy if I can delete and reinsert.

CI = Temp table, CI_Item = Target storage table. CI may have new rows that don't already exist in the CI_Item table.

This provides me with a result set of data to be updated

```
SELECT * FROM CI WHERE ItemCode IN (SELECT ItemCode FROM CI_Item)
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM CI_Item
```

This is my current simple Insert routine

```
PRINT 'Updating CI Item Table...'
INSERT INTO CI_Item
SELECT * FROM CI
WHERE ItemCode NOT IN(SELECT ItemCode FROM CI_Item)
SET @RecordCount = @@ROWCOUNT

DELETE FROM CI
PRINT 'Updated CI Item Table (' + cast(@RecordCount as varchar) + ' records)'
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [`MERGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement? Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Comment: Yes, it is tagged sql-server, for all versions it says ;) I use 2008 (100), but this DB is in 2000 (80) compatibility. If I can get a head start, I can handle the syntax variations. I did look into merge, however the feedback from SO was not positive.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with. I couldn't do a DELETE WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * EXCEPT SELECT *) because it just deleted all rows. So I had to do an IN statement to only affect those returned from the EXCEPT

```
--Common Information (Part Number Detail)
PRINT 'Updating CI Item Table...'

--Remove Any Records With Updated Data
;WITH RecordsWithUpdates AS
(
    SELECT * FROM CI WHERE ItemCode IN (SELECT ItemCode FROM CI_Item)
    EXCEPT
    SELECT * FROM CI_Item
)
DELETE FROM CI_Item WHERE ItemCode IN (SELECT ItemCode FROM RecordsWithUpdates)
SELECT @RecordCount = @@ROWCOUNT

PRINT '-- > CI_Item Table Removing ' + cast(@RecordCount as varchar) + ' Updated Records'

--Insert Any New Records Including Updated Rows
INSERT INTO CI_Item
SELECT * FROM CI
WHERE ItemCode NOT IN(SELECT ItemCode FROM CI_Item)
SET @RecordCount = @@ROWCOUNT

DELETE FROM CI
PRINT 'Updated CI Item Table (' + cast(@RecordCount as varchar) + ' records)'
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server's "set theory operators", `UNION (ALL)`, `EXCEPT` and `INTERSECT` are not really optimal for what you're trying to do. They're great in some situations, notably ad-hoc data comparison and analysis, but it sounds like you're writing something that will be used repeatedly, and that performance matters to you.

An alternative to `EXCEPT` is to do a left join and test for where the join hasn't succeeded, by looking for `null` values in an appropriate (non-nullable) column in the right-hand table.

Something like this (I mocked up some #tables to test this roughly, so treat as a template):

```
-- Equivalent to the EXCEPT: 
select      C.*
from        #CI         C
left join   #CI_Item    T   on C.ItemCode=T.ItemCode
where       T.ItemCode is null

-- Alternative way to delete: 
;with cteChangedRows as (
    select      C.*
    from        #CI         C
    left join   #CI_Item    T   on C.ItemCode=T.ItemCode
    where       T.ItemCode is null
    )
delete      T
from        #CI_Item        T
inner join  cteChangedRows  C   on T.ItemCode=C.ItemCode

-- And insert:
insert into #CI_Item

select      C.*
from        #CI         C
left join   #CI_Item    T   on C.ItemCode=T.ItemCode
where       T.ItemCode is null
```

This is likely to perform much better on larger data sets. As always with SQL, YMMV.

**Edit:**

If you need to account for multiple columns in the joining equivalent to `EXCEPT`, you'd want to do it something like this:

```
select      C.*
from        #CI         C
left join   #CI_Item    T   on C.ItemCode=T.ItemCode
                            and C.Column2=T.Column2
                            and C.Column3=T.Column3
where       T.ItemCode is null
```

If any one of `ItemCode`, `Column2`, or `Column3` don't match between `C` and `T`, then all the `T` columns will be `null` (that's how left joins work), so the `where` clause will bring back those rows. This works provided `T.ItemCode` is never actually `null` in `CI_Item`, which is why I say above you have to pick a non-nullable column to use in the `where` clause.

This approach is clearly more typing than the `EXCEPT` approach, if you have a lot of columns, which is why I say `EXCEPT` is great for ad-hoc stuff. However, for anything you'll write once and run loads of times, this should definitely not be a deterrent.

Comment: I appreciate the info and explanation, however I just ran both the LEFT JOIN and EXCEPT and only the EXCEPT returned rows when any of the columns had changed data. I would have to do an OR on each column in your LEFT JOIN right?

Comment: @AdamRoof I've added an example of how you should do this to my answer.  It's an AND rather than an OR; I've tried to explain why but do say if it's not clear.